# How to load events into fullcalendar.io from a json feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django

Iam stuck with `fullcalendar.io` and the json feed to load the events in to the calendar.

`Json feed 1 with 1 event:` this is working fine the `events` are `fetched` from the json feed in the url and loaded into the calendar.

```
[{"id": 9, "title": "test event", "start": "2023-02-22T03:00:00Z", "end": "2023-02-22T01:03:00Z"}]
```

And the relevant calendar code

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar')
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

        events: { url : '{% url 'calendar_app:all_events' %}' }, --> working fine
```

Json feed 2 with 1 event: this is `not` working, again the events are fetched from the json feed in the url, however the json has a `different` `format`

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "title": "test",
            "start": "2023-02-21T04:30:00Z",
            "end": "2023-02-21T06:55:00Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

What do i have to do to be able to use the second json feed to load the events into the calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to define a function for fetching the events and set that as the `events` property in your FullCalendar constructor call. In this function, you will call your Events API and parse the response to get the events at `results`. You will then pass the events to the `successCallback`. The docs can be found [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function).

The code would look something like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar')
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        $.get('{% url 'calendar_app:all_events' %}')
          .done(function (response) {
            successCallback(response.result);
          })
          .fail(function (err) {
            failureCallback(err);
          });
      }
    });
     
    calendar.render();
  });
```

I am making an assumption about the `{% url 'calendar_app:all_events' %}` part to generate the API URL.

I have created an example with a mock API call [here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/djxrbgLa/).